# passing data to constructor parameters to castle windsor container

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

i want send parameters to constructor in class in iocc,but don't work my code
this is my code:

```
public class InvestigationBox : IInvestigationBox
{
    private long BoxId { get; set; }
    private string BoxIP { get; set; }
    private string BoxPort { get; set; }
    public InvestigationBox(string boxip, int port)
    {
        this.BoxIP = boxip;
        this.BoxPort = port;
    }
} public interface IInvestigationBox
{}
```

and this is my castle windsor config

```
 public static class CastleConfig
{
    public static IWindsorContainer GetContainer()
    {
        var container = new WindsorContainer();
        container.Register(Component.For<IInvestigationBox>()
            .ImplementedBy<InvestigationBox>());
         container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
        return container;
    }
}
```

and i create the factory for create the parametr for constructor
this code for factory:

```
public  interface IInvestigationBoxFactory
{
    IInvestigationBox Create(string boxip, int port);
}
```

and this is my code in webapi:

```
public class LoginCheckController : ApiController
{
    private IHashing _ihashing { get; set; }
    private ITokenValidation _itokenValidation { get; set; }
    private IInvestigationBoxFactory _iInvestigationBoxFactory { get; set; }
    private IInvestigationBox _iInvestigationBox { get; set; }
    public LoginCheckController(IHashing ihashing, ITokenValidation itokenValidation, IInvestigationBoxFactory iInvestigationBoxFactory)
    {
        this._ihashing = ihashing;
        this._itokenValidation = itokenValidation;

         this._iInvestigationBoxFactory = iInvestigationBoxFactory;
    }
  public UserViewModel Get(string id, string id2)
    {        
        _iInvestigationBox = _iInvestigationBoxFactory.Create("100.200", 1020);
    }
```

}
but i have get this error in run time:

Can't create component 'SSM.WebApi.Controllers.LoginCheckController' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

'SSM.WebApi.Controllers.LoginCheckController' is waiting for the following dependencies:
- Service 'SSM.WebApi.Infrastructure.IInvestigationBoxFactory' which was not registered.

Comment: I see where you register `IInvestigationBox`, but I don't see where you register `IInvestigationBoxFactory` with castle Windsor.  In fact, the error says that the Factory is what is missing registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to register your factory

add this:

```
container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
container.Register(
                 Component.For<IInvestigationBoxFactory>()
                          .AsFactory()
               );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class InvestigationBox : IInvestigationBox
{
    private long BoxId { get; set; }
    private string BoxIP { get; set; }
    public InvestigationBox(string boxip, int port)
    {
        this.BoxIP = boxip;
        this.BoxPort = port;
    }
} public interface IInvestigationBox
{}
```

I don't see where this.BoxPort is initialized. Maybe you meant this.BoxId? I'm very new, but I'd fix that and see.

Answer (score 0):

Ok how about this link?

http://docs.castleproject.org/(S(nuulbyzrcrtj4u2bpq0ceq45))/Print.aspx?NS=Windsor&Page=Windsor.Windsor-Tutorial-Part-Nine-Diagnosing-missing-dependency-issues&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

The important bit I think is this:

> We did add the class and interface to the solution, but we didn't       register it. Let's quickly add an installer for it.

EDIT: 
add registration for Factory:

```
public static IWindsorContainer GetContainer()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For<IInvestigationBox>()
        .ImplementedBy<InvestigationBox>());
    container.Register(Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component.For<IInvestigationBoxFactory>()
        .ImplementedBy<IInvestigationBoxFactory>());
    container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<ApiController>().LifestylePerWebRequest());
    return container;
}
```

moved _iInvastigationBox = _iInvestigationBoxFactory.Create("100.200", 1020); to the constructor since it's hard coded anyway.

```
public class LoginCheckController : ApiController
{
    private IInvestigationBoxFactory _iInvestigationBoxFactory { get; set; }
    private IInvestigationBox _iInvestigationBox { get; set; }
    public LoginCheckController(IInvestigationBoxFactory iInvestigationBoxFactory)
    {
        this._iInvestigationBoxFactory = iInvestigationBoxFactory;
        _iInvestigationBox = _iInvestigationBoxFactory.Create("100.200", 1020);
    }
}
```